# How can I pass params in this dispatcher?

Tags: php, parameters, dispatcher

I am working with this [addon code](https://github.com/WHMCS/sample-addon-module/blob/master/modules/addons/addonmodule/lib/Admin/Controller.php#L52):

You see the [Dispatcher](https://github.com/WHMCS/sample-addon-module/blob/master/modules/addons/addonmodule/lib/Admin/AdminDispatcher.php), the [Controller](https://github.com/WHMCS/sample-addon-module/blob/master/modules/addons/addonmodule/lib/Admin/Controller.php) give `index` and `show` dispatcher.

I have a question:

the URL is like: `{$modulelink}&action=show`

but how can I pass params in this type dispatcher?  such as `{$modulelink}&action=show&age=25&gender=1`, then I in [`show`](https://github.com/WHMCS/sample-addon-module/blob/master/modules/addons/addonmodule/lib/Admin/Controller.php#L72) can get the params `age=25` and `gender=1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just define them inside [this function](https://github.com/WHMCS/sample-addon-module/blob/master/modules/addons/addonmodule/lib/Admin/Controller.php#L72):

```
$age = isset($_REQUEST['age']) ? $_REQUEST['age'] : '';
```

Extending it by following the "module's way" requires editing code in a few places and it's not that flexible so I suggest the above solution.